# dataframe.groupby changing dtypes of empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

So i'm not sure if the following is intentional per se, but this appears to be a change in behavior from pandas 0.18.0 which I was previously using.  I've updated to 0.23.0 and I'm getting some odd behavior...

Let's say I have some large dataframe, called `dfLarge` and I am taking a subset `df` from it based on some criteria.  (This part of the problem is not really necessary for reproduction but it is from my actual use case and how I noticed the change in pandas behavior).  But it just so happens that I wasn't able to get a match on the criteria I was looking for in `dfLarge`, and so `df` is empty.

What is important is that `df` shares the same `dtypes` as `dfLarge`. In general, it might look like this for some `df`:

```
In [187]: df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['field1','field2','field3','num1','num2'])

In [188]: df['num1'] = df['num1'].astype('float64')  # assume this was inherited from dfLarge

In [189]: df['num2'] = df['num2'].astype('float64')  # assume this was inherited from dfLarge

In [190]: df.dtypes
Out[190]:
field1     object
field2     object
field3     object
num1      float64
num2      float64
dtype: object
```

So now we have some fields and different datatypes for an empty dataframe `df`.  As I aggregate my data using `df.groupby` while maintaining my index by summing across `field1` and `field2`, the resultant dataframe changes the `dtype` of my fields.

```
In [191]: dfGrouped = df.groupby(['field1','field2'])[['num1','num2']].sum().reset_index(level=['field1','field2'])

In [192]: dfGrouped.dtypes
Out[192]:
field1     float64
field2     float64
num1       float64
num2       float64
dtype: object
```

As far I can see from the pandas documentation, `df.groupby` is not supposed to do this, and I only discovered change in behavior from pandas 0.18.0 (where the `dtypes` do not change) as I ran into subsequent `TypeErrors` when I tested various `fields` against some strings.  Is there any way to handle this gracefully, as opposed to assigning my `dtypes` to a new object before the `groupby` and reapplying them in a `df['field'] = df['field'].astype('newtype')` manner? Thank you.

Comment: **NB:** This has been [fixed](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/34942) in pandas 1.1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `as_index=False` when specifying your [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

I believe this bug is caused by setting and resetting an empty `MultiIndex` (`groupby` sets the `MultiIndex`, then you reset it).  See [#19602](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/19602) on the GitHub issue tracker.  Using `as_index=False` prevents this pattern from occurring, since the `MultiIndex` won't get set by `groupby` in the first place.

```
In [2]: pd.__version__
Out[2]: '0.23.0'

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['field1','field2','field3','num1','num2'])
   ...: df = df.astype({'num1': 'float64', 'num2': 'float64'})

In [4]: df.dtypes
Out[4]:
field1     object
field2     object
field3     object
num1      float64
num2      float64
dtype: object

In [5]: dfGrouped = df.groupby(['field1','field2'], as_index=False)[['num1','num2']].sum()

In [6]: dfGrouped.dtypes
Out[6]:
field1     object
field2     object
num1      float64
num2      float64
dtype: object
```

Note that this should preserve the behavior for non-empty DataFrames too:

```
In [7]: df = pd.DataFrame({'field1': list('aaaa'),
   ...:                    'field2': list('0101'),
   ...:                    'field3': list('wxyz'),
   ...:                    'num1': [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0],
   ...:                    'num2': [10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0]})

In [8]: df
Out[8]:
  field1 field2 field3  num1  num2
0      a      0      w   0.0  10.0
1      a      1      x   1.0  11.0
2      a      0      y   2.0  12.0
3      a      1      z   3.0  13.0

In [9]: dfGrouped = df.groupby(['field1','field2'], as_index=False)[['num1','num2']].sum()

In [10]: dfGrouped.dtypes
Out[10]:
field1     object
field2     object
num1      float64
num2      float64
dtype: object

In [11]: dfGrouped
Out[11]:
  field1 field2  num1  num2
0      a      0   2.0  22.0
1      a      1   4.0  24.0
```

Comment: Make sense, appreciate the help.